Difference between @Repository @Entity @Configuration in spring boot
I think these all are used for the detection of beans??
If there work are only for the detection of use than why they are different??
Anyone please help me in understanding the concept and tell me the real meaning and use of these three annotations.

Did you read Spring Boot docs to understand same?

do you see any difference between nouns, pro-nouns and verbs? I mean, after all: they're all words, right? Yes, they're all Beans, but they have different functions. You can easily read up on them on your own

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
